# Automate the github repository push process

Tags: bash, git, github

I'm trying to write a bash script to automatically fill the username and access token when pushed to the github repository.
any hint to make that?

thanks in advance

The initial thought that I put forward was to put in the username and access token in `.env` file.

But how do I call them, fill in the username, and automatically redirect to fill out the access token?

To clarify more:

When the username and access token are requested via the terminal, how do I retrieve them from the env file and fill them in automatically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you check out via ssh, you can just push to the remote. Your ssh configuration knows the user name and key to use for gihtub.com. What git command are you running? What happens then? Please check [ask].

Comment: Doesn't Git credential manager take care of this? https://github.blog/2022-04-07-git-credential-manager-authentication-for-everyone/

Answer (score 1):

If git credential manager does not work for some reason like mine.

add a .gitconfig file containing

```
[user]
    name = user
    email = user@gmail.com
    password = user
[credential]
    helper = store
```

then create a .git-credentials containing

```
https://username.com:token from settings > developer settings generate personal access token>@github.com
```

in my case the files are saved on C:\Users\username

Answer (score 0):

you can call the variables from the .env file whit echo

```
echo "Username: $USERNAME"
echo "Access Token: $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

hope this helps